# Why GCP persistent SSD disks so slow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have 500GB SSD Persistent disk in us-central1 on custom VM (4 vCPUs, 18 GB memory)

It used for PostgreSQL 10. (Cloud SQL can not be used for some reasons: there is no way to migrate without reasonable downtime, etc)

[image]

GCP promised 15k IOPS for that disk, but in real it is 5k. postgres processes stuck (up to 50%) in IOWait state

[image]
[image]

Some details:
Spikes are data processing jobs running on app server (not on the DB server) which request large amount of data from postgresql by primary key.

What is wrong with GCP disks, why SSD disks so slow ?

```
iostat 10

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          13.06    0.00   10.84   37.13    0.00   38.97

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
loop0             0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sda               5.00        27.20        24.00        272        240
sdb            5310.90     41790.00       883.60     417900       8836

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          13.46    0.00   10.83   35.85    0.00   39.86

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
loop0             0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sda               5.00         0.80        34.00          8        340
sdb            4962.40     38276.00      1578.40     382760      15784
```

[image]

**UPD**: Upgraded VM, but without success:
[image]

Comment: GCP doesn't *promise* 15k IOPS; that's the *maximum* you'll get.

Comment: Wow. If you are right then 0 IOPS either normal situation.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate theory: the bottleneck is not the disk.

iowait is a common state for a database under load, even SSDs are slow relative to DRAM. However, that top output also shows quite a lot of idle cycles and sleeping processes. More so than I expect for a problem purely limited by the disk.

Find the limit of the disk independently from the DBMS. Use a synthetic IO generator like `fio` on a similar instance to try for 15k IOPS. If the advertised performance is achievable, the bottleneck is elsewhere.

Look into database performance analysis tools to get an deeper idea of what is going on, and what is waiting. [Query plan analysis](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions) will show what it is trying to do. [Collected statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/monitoring-stats.html) will tell exactly what the backend was waiting for, and can be shown in [nice visualizations](https://powa.readthedocs.io/). Waits for client or locks or something else could limit throughput below what the disk is theoretically capable of.

Comment: Got 15k with `fio`, looks like it is synthetic test and do not reflect db usage scenario. 
Because previously (before migrating to GCP) we have problems with vps with local SSDs.
Thanks, I will research further.

Comment: The entire point of going to fio was to not use a DBMS. It was to prove this disk type can do however many IOPS, a simple brutal test of the storage system.  Now you know it is necessary to look at how the DBMS is tuned, and what your queries look like.

Answer (score 3):

I have created one VM in us-central1-a with custom custom (4 vCPUs, 18 GB memory) and 500gb SSD and run [fio](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/optimizing-pd-performance?hl=id#benchmark_ssd_pd_perf) and found `iops=14995` so i am agreed with [@John Mahowald](https://serverfault.com/users/241174/john-mahowald)  it's not the disk which restricted the iops

Comment: Yes, I have performed `fio` and found ~15K IOPS either. In my opinion `fio` is a synthetic test  and does not reflect real (db) usage scenario.
I will research further.
Thanks!